# How to configure tsconfig.json file to include .ts files of an angular library project?

Tags: angular, build, tsconfig, angular-library

I have created an angular 8 library project! It is a simple data table with bootstrap 4. Now I am facing some problems. When I install in via npm in a new project, compile fails with the an error which told me that some files are missing like bellow:

> Error: /home/atheodosiou/Documents/development/kino-statistics/node_modules/ng-bootstrap-table/src/lib/directives/b-body.directive.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

[image]

My library's tsconfig.json file is the following (I have read that if I am not specify the files of include properties, compiler would include all .ts files):

```
    {
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "docs/",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ],
    "noEmitOnError": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have tried to include all of them via the include property and also to declare them via the files property (not at the same time).

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The way I've seen all files included is to have

```
"include": ["**/*.ts"]
```

I believe that your exclude statement should still exclude the files you requested.